# What can I use in place of sherry in a recipe with king prawns, garlic and paprika?

Tags: substitutions

I'm going to try out a recipe containing prawns for the first time. The recipe includes sherry, but I don't want to purchase a bottle of sherry as I don't drink and don't use it for cooking so I fear it will go to waste. What could I use in its place?

The recipe also calls for paprika, chilli flakes, garlic, tomatoes, breadcrumbs, red onion and parsley.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions :-)

Comment: Related Questions: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17670/what-to-use-instead-of-white-wine-in-recipes/17673#17673, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/829/what-would-be-a-good-substitute-for-rice-wine & http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-is-a-substitute-for-red-or-white-wine-in-a-recipe

Comment: Sometimes supermarkets will sell alcohol freqently used for cooking (sherry, marsala, etc.) in 100 ml bottles together with the cooking ingredients (not in the alcohol section). It is worth getting those if it is a kind of alcohol you don't drink.

Comment: Be careful of the 'cooking' versions of wines ... they're often salted heavily, so that they can't be drunk straight.  (it's required in my state, as stores can't sell alcohol w/out a liquor license).  Check the ingredients to be sure; if there's salt, you'll want to leave out any other salt, and taste the dish before adjusting the seasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any other alcohol (cooking or otherwise) in the house? A dry white wine could work. I usually have rice wine (Japanese, Chinese) or Sake around as I do a lot of Asian cooking, that would easily work too.

Comment: I might try the white wine, I'm more likely to use that in other dishes and I'm partial to the occassional glass :) From reading the questions linked here in the comment above, Vermouth seems like a good choice. If I can find the 100ml bottle of sherry rumtscho, I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

A dry white wine, or white vermouth.

For the more adventurous, a cognac or armagnac would also be very nice (my preference!).  If the pan is hot enough, you can also make it a flambé!